# cubes.errors.ConfigurationError: config should be a ConfigParser instance, but is <type 'instance'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, types, instance

I am trying to use [cubes workspace](https://pythonhosted.org/cubes/reference/workspace.html) and it's required to use a `ConfigParser` instance when creating the workspace. I tried as below:

```
from cubes import Workspace
import ConfigParser

configg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
print configg
print type(configg)
configg.read('slicer.ini')
workspace = Workspace(config=configg)
```

Following is the output:

```
<ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance at 0x0387F148>
Traceback (most recent call last):
<type 'instance'>
  File "C:/Users/saiki/PycharmProjects/bcubes2/b_cubes.py", line 8, in <module>
    workspace = Workspace(config=configg)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cubes\workspace.py", line 83, in __init__
cubes.errors.ConfigurationError: config should be a ConfigParser instance, but is <type 'instance'>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `workspace = Workspace(config='slicer.ini')`.

Comment: it gives  the error: config should be a ConfigParser instance, but is <type 'str'>

Comment: OK. Instead of `import ConfigParser` do `from cubes.compat import ConfigParser` and later `configg = ConfigParser()`.

Comment: thank u so much Mike :) I would like to accept it as answer if u post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
import ConfigParser
```

to:

```
from cubes.compat import ConfigParser
```

and make an instance of it:

```
configg = ConfigParser().
```

The `cubes` library uses a compatibility module to make it work with Python 2 and 3. It does the following:

```
if py3k:
    # ...
    from configparser import ConfigParser
    # ...
else:
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser as ConfigParser
    # ...
```

So, if you are in Python 2 two you need a `SafeConfigParser` instance.
Simpler: Just use `cubes.compat.ConfigParser`.

Even better: Switch to Python 3. :)